# IE8 Browser Mode vs IE8 in XP Mode CSS renders differenty?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

*Please forgive me if I placed this in the wrong section of Stack Exchange, I will be happy to repost elsewhere, Im just not sure which section to go to.*

Why does IE8 display differently in **Browser Mode** (which is accessible through the IE10 F12 Developer Tools) than in **XP Mode**?

It seems that the CSS is rendered differently. Does anyone know the details as to why this occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IE8 Browser Mode vs IE8 in XP Mode CSS renders differenty?

Yep, that's a pretty well-documented problem. It may be called compatibility mode, but the fact is, it isn't really all that compatible.

This is why it's generally considered a bad idea to use compatibility mode to do your testing.

Ultimately the only reliable way to test that a site works in IE8 is to actually load it in a real copy of IE8. XP Mode is a good way to do that.

I agree it's more of a hassle than switching the mode in IE10, but unfortunately, that's the way it is.

Comment: It amazes me that IE is constantly allowed to get away with garbage. It is a total hindrance to progress. Thanks for the clarification!